# Where and how to set an SQL request for a form element?

Tags: sql, symfony, query-builder

I read a lot of things of things in the cookbook or on stackoverflow but I can't find something adapted and clearly explained about how to solve my problem.

I have an SQL request that allows me to find schools that teaches a specific subject. I need to set this SQL request so that when I load the page containing my form, the request is done and I see the result (a list of school) in a multi select form. My best guess is that I need to set it inside my controller, but then again, I'm not even sure of that since it's the first time that I need to do that

I don't know if I should show you any code, so ask if you need to see something!

Thank you in advance

**edit** Here is my formType

```
<?php

namespace MissionBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use SocieteBundle\Entity\Societe;

class PublicType extends AbstractType{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('public')
            ->add('ecolesDispo')
            // My goal is to replace 'ecolesDispo' (that is currently a one-to-many) 
            // by my SQL request. 
      ;

    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MissionBundle\Entity\Mission'
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be better if you post your code.. the minimal essential part to figure out the problem and help to find a solution

Answer (score 4):

Surely not in the controller. You need to use the "query_builder" attribute when you add the field to the form. Take a look at this example, from the Symfony cookbook : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities

And you should translate your raw SQL query into DQL, so it's database-agnostic.

**UPDATE about using a query builder with native SQL** : http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#the-nativequery-class

So something like this following piece of code should work (you'll have to edit some property names and fill the query though)

```
$builder->add('ecolesDispo', EntityType::class, array(
'class' => 'AppBundle:Ecole',
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
    return $er->createNativeQuery('SELECT * FROM ecoles WHERE [...]');
},
'choice_label' => 'title',
```

));

Comment: Thank you for answer, I'm going to ask a newbie question, but is there a way to set a query_builder with pure SQL inside? That's what I'm struggling to find on the web

Comment: I just updated my answer. take a look at it and tell me if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear answer ! However, used / adapted your code for my needs, however I now have this error: `Undefined method 'createNativeQuery'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!`

Comment: try with createNativeNamedQuery(). If it doesn't work, you might need to do something more complicated : First, create a custom method in your EcoleRepository, with your raw SQL query. Then, register this repository as a service. Then, register your form type as a service and inject the repository in it. Finally, use the EcoleRepository in the query_builder attribute

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I now have the following error: `No query found named [my sql request ] class 'EcoleBundle\Entity\Ecole`. So I guess I will do as you advise, I'll keep you in touch!